# Can't add application to the dock

Tags: release-hera, applications, plank, pantheon

I know how to add a running application to the dock; but how can I start an Application, which I know must be present, but I don't know the location? For instance, in a Mac, I would search the `/Applications` and `$HOME/Applications` directory and their sub directories, but Elementary OS doesn't seem to have something similar. The most promising match seems to be a file /usr/share/applications, but there don't seem to be executables in this directory.

As a concrete example, I would like to start the *Pantheon* file manager, which, according to [what I have read](https://linuxhint.com/elementary_os_file_manager/), should already come with Elementary OS. I tried a

```
find / -name 'pantheon-*' 2>/dev/null
```

to locate this program, and found a few matches (for instance as a directory `/usr/share/doc/pantheon-files`), but nothing which would look like a suitable executable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "files" is "pantheon files". It seems to be their strategy to fork everything and simplify it to unusability.

Comment: But this `pantheon-files` which I found, is not an executable file, but a directory; moreover, it is in the `doc` directory where I would expect documentation, not applications!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem turned out to be a double reboot: After the second reboot, my desktop suddenly contained not only the dock at the bottom, but also a small kind of "status line" on the very top, which on the left had an entry saying *Applications*. This status line did not exist before. When clicking on it, I get a list of applications installed, including a File Manager (don't know whether this is Pantheon or not). I still don't know, which directory they are in, but at least I can now start an application from there, and then arrange to keep it in the dock.

Comment: Yes,Files application is Pantheon Files,`io.elementary.files` launches pantheon files. Most executables resides in a /bin folder, for example `/usr/bin` but unlike the macOS you cannot add exec into the Plank, you have to add a `.desktop` file, which contains information for the exec, icon etc, and most of these files are into `/usr/share/applications/` and `~/.local/share/applications/` folders. Ofcourse, there can be exceptions for executable and desktop files which do not reside in these locations. **Please accept your answer as a correct one in order all of us to know that it is resolved**

Comment: I am a bit reluctant to accept my answer, because if it were correct, it would mean that as a general rule, you can the small topmost status line appear on the desktop by doing a reboot twice, and I doubt that Apple has intendet it in this way. Hence I hope someone would give a better answer to my question, and this I certainly will accept. An alternative would be to **close** the question on the grounds that the problem is not reproducible, but I don't have sufficient reputation to close questions.

Comment: @Borislav : Forget my reference to Apple in my previous comment. Of course Elementary Linux is not related to MacOS, except that there are some similarities on the surface. But still I don't think that it is in the spirit of Linux to require reboots to get a problems such as I had resolved.